# In pandas dataframe, how do I perform operations on select rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'B':[1.1,1.3,1.35,1.43,1.5,1.54,1.6]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I want to create a new df where the values are based on operating over column B in df1.

Each row in the new df2['Output']:

```
 = -B[i] + 2*B[i+1] -B[i+2]
```

where I represents the row number.

The new name of each row in df2 should combine the numbers in column A.

The resulting dataframe should look like this

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Output':[0.15,-0.03,0.01,0.03,-0.02]})

df2['Name'] = ['123', '234','345','456','567']
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to your logic:

```
df2 = (df['B'].shift() * 2 - df['B'] - df['B'].shift(2)).to_frame(name='Output')
```

Or you can do

```
df2 = (-df['B'].diff().diff()).to_frame(name='Output')
```

Output:

```
   Output
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    0.15
3   -0.03
4    0.01
5    0.03
6   -0.02
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, the resulting dataframe should only contain the non NaN value (for which i,i+1 and i+2 are valid). I think the answer would also require little modification on what @Quang Hoang has provided.

```
df2 = (df1['B'].shift() * 2 - df1['B'] - df1['B'].shift(2)).to_frame(name='Output').shift(-2).dropna()
```

**Output**:

```
>>> df2 = (df1['B'].shift() * 2 - df1['B'] - df1['B'].shift(2)).to_frame(name='Output').shift(-2).dropna()
>>> df2
   Output
0    0.15
1   -0.03
2    0.01
3    0.03
4   -0.02
```